# how to use group by in flask sql alchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two tables

```
class MinMaxDim(db.Model):
   min_max_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
   room_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
   min_temp = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
   max_temp = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
   min_humidity = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
   max_humidity = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
   min_pressure = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
   max_pressure = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)


class AvgDim(db.Model):
  avg_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
  room_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
  avg_temp = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
  avg_humidity = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
  avg_pressure = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
```

**Requirements:**

- I will send room_id as an argument to the function, It should return the last 7 days min_temp, max_temp, and avg_temp values from the two tables.

**What I have tried:**

I have created a function in that I have used group_by function but I am getting this error:

```
  (psycopg2.errors.GroupingError) column "min_max_dim.min_max_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause 
   or be used in an aggregate function
```

**My code**:

```
     def get_weekly_dim_dataInfo(room_id):
        try:
           get_all_data = db.session.query(MinMaxDim).outerjoin(AvgDim, MinMaxDim.user_id ==
                           MinMaxDim.tenant_id).group_by(MinMaxDim.room_id).all()
           get_all_data_schema = MinMaxDimSchema(many=True).dump(get_all_data)
           get_all_avg_data_schema = AvgDimSchema(many=True).dump(get_all_data)
           print(get_all_data)
         except Exception as e:
             print(e)
             return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
get_all_data = db.session.query(MinMaxDim).outerjoin(AvgDim, MinMaxDim.user_id == MinMaxDim.tenant_id).group_by(MinMaxDim.min_max_id, MinMaxDim.room_id).all()
```

Just as the error suggests, you need to have `min_max_id` in the group by clause.

Curiously though, you can refactor your models so as to take advantage of postgresql [aggregate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/tutorial-agg.html) functions instead of trying to model around aggregated results.